# How to set "feed options" inside a stored procedure in DocumentDB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm editing the Stored Procedure in DocumentDB inside the Portal.

Starting from the sample SP azure is offering.

in the part :

```
 var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
    collection.getSelfLink(),
    'SELECT * FROM r WHERE r.ProductId = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"',
    function (err, feed, options) {
        if (err) throw err;
```

the feed only get 100 results. How do I change it ?
Where can I find a reference to this functions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `pageSize` parameter of the `FeedOptions` object is what you need. `FeedOptions` is the third parameter on a `QueryDocuments(...)` call.

Here is a link to the documentation for it:

http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-js-server/Collection.html#.FeedOptions

To make the page size 1000, your updated snippet would look like this:

```
var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
  collection.getSelfLink(),
  'SELECT * FROM r WHERE r.ProductId = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"',
  {pageSize: 1000},
  function (err, feed, options) {
    if (err) throw err;
```